# how to un-pivot multi-column data?

Tags: python, unpivot

I am trying to Unpivot columns and get 1 attributes and 2 value from a pandas dataframe, could anyone help me on this?

original data:

```
 id Jan-Value1 Jan-Value2 Feb-Value1 Feb-Value2
 1  1          10         2          15
 2  0          5          3          20
```

desire output:

```
 id Month Value1 Value2
 1  Jan   1      10
 1  Feb   2      15
 2  Jan   0      5
 2  Feb   3      20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to do this is to use [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) and [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html). For this solution, I am assuming that `id` is the index of the dataframe:

```
#df.set_index('id',inplace=True)  #set 'id' as index

#creating a Multiindex using existing columns 
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('-', expand=True).swaplevel(0,1)

#stacking the dataframe
df = df.stack().reset_index()

#renaming the column 
df.rename(columns={'level_1':'Month'},inplace=True)
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
   id Month  Value1  Value2
0   1   Feb       2      15
1   1   Jan       1      10
2   2   Feb       3      20
3   2   Jan       0       5
```

Comment: Added an answer. Let me know if it works for you. If it does please consider accepting/check-marking the answer

Answer (score 0):

You might consider pandas.wide_to_long():

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
"Jan-Value1": [1, 0],
"Jan-Value2": [10, 5],
"Feb-Value1": [2, 3],
"Feb-Value2": [15,20]
})

df.columns = ["-".join(col.split("-")[::-1]) for col in df.columns]

df["id"] = df.index

transformed_df = pd.wide_to_long(df, ["Value1", "Value2"], i="id", j="Month", sep="-", suffix="\w+")
```

Since pandas requires the suffix to end up in a value of the column, I ended up reversing the order of your column names (without that transform, Value1 and Value2 ended up in the months column)